# Editing the values while changing Django model field type

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a field in my Django model:

`state = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

I want to change the field type to:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (Enabled, 'Enabled'),
    (Disabled, 'Disabled'),
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
)
models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=Pending)
```

Currently there is content in my model table with boolean values (`1` or `0`).
How can I migrate this change and also transforming the existing values `1` to `Enabled` and `0` to `Disabled`?

Comment: One solution is  to manually change the value at `./manage.py shell` after makemigration and  migate.

Comment: in your example you have  boolean values `false/true` why you write `0` `1`